# Is "you might have already had dinner" correct order-wise?

Tags: word-order, modal-verbs

I said this to a friend of mine, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not, in terms of word order.

You might have already had dinner.

Or maybe the correct way is: You might already have had dinner?

Thank you.

Comment: You missed out at least *You might have had dinner already* (and some other admittedly less *likely* positions for the adverb).

Comment: As the link you provided says: "The following adverbs can come at the end of the sentence or before the main verb" . Therefore, I understand that the sentence is correct, as well as the one you suggested with the adverb ending the sentence. Thank you.

Comment: It might be less *likely*, but syntactically there's nothing wrong with putting the adverb before everything else: *Already you might have had dinner*. Come to that, I don't think *You already might have had dinner* is inherently invalid - it's just incredibly unlikely.

Comment: If you're asking what Jo Speaker might really say on an average day, that would prolly be "You might already have had dinner."

Otherwise, don't you think this belongs somewhere like SE English Language Leaners?

Comment: Apologies for my misuse of the site. I lack experience in StackExchange sub-sites as I do not use them much, so I though it was appropriate to ask the question here.